# flash getting struck in 14.04 from 1 day

Tags: 14.04, firefox, google-chrome, flash

From 1day, I am unable to watch videos in firefox(I think its 33 version that time). 
So, today I installed latest version of firefox, chrome, flash.

Now, firefox not showing that warning, but the video gets struck every few seconds.  I have to move a few seconds ahead to get it working.

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Same struck happening in chrome.

I donno if its really flash problem but I have done one extra thing.
I download a deb file for some screensharing and installed that. while installing it said it had no proper standards(just warning), so I proceeded. I think its not problem as the installed software is working properly, but mentioning.

Any faced this problem recently ?

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me as as though something is interfering with your internet speed.  Several causes are possible.  If you have cable as opposed to FIOS, comcast in particular is well known for dialing back your performance if you exceed their predetermined expectations of your "unlimited internet".

Other possibilities include wifi interference if you are using wifi.  If a neighbor installs a new wifi router and it is on the same radio frequency channel, especially a popular default one like 6 or 11 and that's what you have, the interference will cause internet dropouts.  To diagnose that I recommend installing "WIFI RADAR" and letting it sit for at least 30 minutes to see what channels are being used near you.  When you find out, you can log into your wifi router and manually change your channel.

Also if you have a cell phone or cordless phone handy... like the rest of us, please try to keep it as far from your wifi device and router as possible as it too can result in slowness.

I'm guessing one of these is right, and if so, please tell me which one worked for you.

Comment: Internet is very fast, also video is loading fast... sometimes i am seeing 'flash crashed'. Mobiles etc are not reason for me.

Comment: Is it possible your graphics chipset is not supported properly?  I'm thinking maybe you installed one of the "additional drivers" and it didn't work so well.  I've found some of them to be problematic.  Would you please list the graphics card/chipset in your reply?

Answer (score -1):

i used to solve it with forcing flash player instead of html5 - eventhough you have flash plugin installed, many websites turned to html5 by default.

there used to be an option on youtube.com/html5 to turn on/off the html5 player, but nowdays its gone. try to use some browser plugin which forces to use flash instead of html5